# Looking for a two-level bridge somewhere near Xanthi, Greece

Tags: trains, driving, greece, locate-this

A friend of mine told me he knew some stories about some bridge in Greece, supposedly near [Xanthi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthi), the bridge is on two levels, and both trains and cars pass through it, but I can't find it anywhere on the maps.

Anyone have any idea where it is located?

Comment: Wikipedia maintains a list of multi-level bridges and has none in Greece: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multi-level_bridges

Comment: The Wikipedia list is not complete, though. The second example of such a bridge I could think of (_Sankt Eriksbron_ in Stockholm) was not in the list; I have now added it.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the rail map for the area near Xanthi and couldn't locate any two-level bridges:

[image: rail xanthi map]

While a two level bridge may exist somewhere else in Greece, there definitely isn't one near Xanthi.

Comment: Disused railway?

Answer (score -1):

You must be referring to a bridge near in Toxotes, a small village near Xanthi close to Nestos. I have been walking a lot near there as there are some trekking routes.

See if you can see it on the link (Greek only):

http://users.sch.gr/ppapachr/nestos/nestos.html

Comment: I don't see any bridge on the linked page.

Comment: there is no photo as such. no. but the place must there.

Comment: @Pixie: Why do you think this purported bridge must be there, as opposed to somewhere else?  I looked at the Google aerial view of Toxotes; there are two road bridges in the immediate vicinity, and neither of them appear to be two-level, as far as I can tell.  As it stands, I am not really sure how your answer is helpful to the asker.

Comment: Could you provide a translation of (some) relevant parts of the text?

Comment: @Nate let's not let google control our decisions here. It is possible its not there... I have seen such a bridge there. I do not know if that is the one. That is all I am saying.

Comment: @Pixie: Oh, you have actually *seen* this bridge?  That wasn't clear to me from your answer.  It sounded like you were just guessing as to where the asker should look.

Comment: sooo, anything?